# Matrix representation of a linear map in other basis

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis, transition-matrix

Recently I was asked on my linear algebra course the following question:

*Suppose the map $\varphi:L \rightarrow M$ has the matrix
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-2&1\\1&-1&0\\2&-2&0\\-2&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$
in some pair of bases($e$, $f$). Can it have the matrix 
$$A' = \begin{bmatrix}2&-1&2\\0&2&-2\\0&1&-1\\-1&2&2\end{bmatrix}$$
in some other pair of bases?($e'$, $f'$)*

I know that the relationship between $A'$ and $A$ is given by
$$ A' = T^{-1} A S $$
Where $S$ is the transition matrix $e \rightarrow e'$ and $T$ is the transition matrix $f \rightarrow f'$. But how to find them? Or how to prove that they don't exist? 
Also I see that $det(A) = det(A^{-1}) = 0$ but I don't think it will help me here.

It really doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. The columns of the matrix $A$ sum to $0$ so it has rank $2$. On the other hand, the rank of the matrix $A'$ is $3$.